# Determine whether supremum of $S$ exist, if it does determine its value.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, real-numbers

Consider the set $S = \left \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : x < \frac{3}{x} \right \}$
Determine if supremum of $S$ exist, if it does, determine its value.

How do I approach this question? I can't multiply by $x$ since I'm not sure if its negative or positive.

Any ideas or insight is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since $S$ has positive elements, we expect the supremum to be positive. So you can without loss of generality study the subset of S with $x>0$.

Edit: We know (check it) that $S$ is non empty, and is clearly a subset of R thats bounded above. We can then see that $S$ has positive elements, and knowing that the supremum is larger than or equal to all elements of $S$, we would expect it to be positive. Then, for $x>0$ we have $x^2<3$. So we would expect $\sup S$ to be $\sqrt{3}$ at this point and it remains to verify that.

Comment: This does not exactly answer the question nor does it provide a sufficient hint.

Comment: Ok, so we know (check it) that S is non empty, and is clearly a subset of R thats bounded above. We can then see that S has positive elements, and knowing that the supremum (sup S) is larger than or equal to all elements of S, we would expect sup S to be positive. Then, for x>0 we have x^2<3. We would expect sup S to be root 3 at this point and it remains to verify that.

Comment: So it would be nice if you put parts of this in your answer

Comment: Sure, i'll edit it

Answer (score 0):

You know $S$ contains positive elements (like 1), hence the supremum of $S$ is also the supremum of $S$ intersect the positive reals. Then multiply by $x$ until your heart is content :)

Comment: This does not exactly provide an answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

Through simple manipulation of the definition of $S$ we have 
$$S = \lbrace x \in \mathbb{R} : x^2 < 3 \land x > 0 \rbrace \cup \lbrace x \in \mathbb{R} : x^2 \gt 3 \land x \lt 0 \rbrace$$
$$ \Rightarrow S = \lbrace x \in \mathbb{R} : x < \sqrt{3} \land x > 0 \rbrace \cup \lbrace x \in \mathbb{R} : x^2 \gt 3 \land x \lt 0 \rbrace$$

It follows from the definition of $S$ that $S$ is bounded from above by $\sqrt{3}$. $S$ is non-empty since $1 \in S$. Since $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, it follows from the completeness axiom that $\sup S$ exists. It's not hard to see now that $\sup S = \sqrt{3}$.